# CakePHP specify table-name

Tags: cakephp

I have a table called `entries` with an associated model called `Entry`. I stepped through the Blog-tutorial on the CakePHP website. It states that the table-name does not need to be specified because it is computed from the models name. ( `Post => posts`).

I doubt CakePHP knows that `Entry` is a non-conform noun when it comes to its plural form. So how can I set the table my model uses? I think CakePHP would otherwise try to access the table `entrys`.

Comment: Doubt all you want, but you're wrong. (If you do need to specify a table name, however, the Model docs will tell you how.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom table names in CakePHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516919/custom-table-names-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer to your question is to specify it inside your model.

```
$useTable = 'yourtablename'
```

Although, as Wooble noted, your doubts are wrong.

Comment: You need to also include the privacy attribute which will be *public* or *private* in your case you would want to use public.

Answer (score 1):

Cakephp 3, use this instead:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html

```
class MyTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->setTable('my_table');
        $this->setAlias('MyTable');
    }
}
```