# Cakephp table name error

Tags: cakephp

I created a table named as **`quantities_master`** but when i using modal name as **`QuantitiesMaster`** it is showing some errors. what would be modal name of **`quantities_master`** table name?

Comment: What's the error ?After bake did you see this error ?

Comment: error is not readable , i means just breaking UI.

Comment: table name should be quantity_masters. But if you use this model name, you have to define it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394418/cakephp-specify-table-name

Answer (score 0):

The model is looking for `quantities_masters` table. Add this line at the beginning of the class and it will work fine:

```
class QuantitiesMaster extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'quantities_master';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Table names should be plural and model names singular in CakePHP. So you should have a table named `quantities_masters` and a `QuantitiesMaster` model.

However, if you *need* to have a table with a singular name you can define this in the model.

In CakePHP 2:-

```
class QuantitiesMaster extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'quantities_master';

}
```

In CakePHP 3:-

```
class QuantitiesMasterTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('quantities_master');
    }

}
```

Only ever break from CakePHP's naming conventions when you have no other choice as it makes working with CakePHP significantly harder!

If you find determining the plural and singular of words for CakePHP (*i.e* if English is not your first language) then the [CakePHP Inflector website](http://inflector.cakephp.org/) is really handy.